# How to change XML node JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I am trying to create a rating system.

I have an XML file, which has the follow information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<PROGRAMMEDATA> 
    <PROGRAMME id="1">
        <TITLE>Arrow</TITLE>
        <IMAGE>img/arrow.jpg</IMAGE>
        <POINTS>0</POINTS>
    </PROGRAMME>
    ...etc
<PROGRAMMEDATA>
```

I then have a form, with programme options and 1 to 5 score.

```
<form>
    <select id="name">
        <option selected value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Arrow</option>
        <option value="2">You, Me and Dupree</option>
        <option value="3">Fargo</option>
        <option value="4">Flash</option>
    </select>
    <select id="rating">
        <option selected value="">stars</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit rating" onClick="saveRating()" />
</form>
```

The idea is you can choose a programme and then choose a rating. You can then submit that and the rating will then be added to the corresponding programme in the XML file.

I have tried to capture the form values with javascript, but I then don't know how to store the value in the XML file.

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var rating = document.getElementById("rating").value;
```

Another way I've thought about is using PHP, and using DOMDocument, however I can't get it to append the POINTS, it only adds to the bottom of the XML file.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say append the points, but do you mean sum the points? Can you please share the php you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$file ="ratings_file.xml";

$title="test";
$image="img/arrow.jpg";
$points=0;

//load xml object
$xml= simplexml_load_file($ratings_file);

//assign title
$xml->PROGRAMME->title = $title;

//assign image
$xml->PROGRAMME->image = $image;

//assign points
$xml->PROGRAMME->points = $points;

//store the value into the file
file_put_contents($ratings_file, $xml->asXML());
```